# Empty parentheses vs underscore for ES6 no-args arrow functions

Tags: javascript, coding-style, ecmascript-6

This is more of a code style question.

In ES6, we can define arrow functions like so

```
let hello = () => console.log('world')
```

We can also replace `()` with `_` to save one character, but jslint warns that `_` is unused. 
So my question is should one use underscore instead of empty parentheses?

Comment: It depends on every person, also I think `_` is creating an unused variable space in memmory. Why would you want to save one character?

Comment: Difference between a broken tie fighter =()=> and a, well something squinting =_=> is not worth debate. All that matters with style is that you are consistent throughout the file and the project. It is the `let` that I burn my students for. They better have dam good reason for block scope to let that currently crippled javascript token into their code.

Comment: @Blindman67 var is dead. long live let (and const).

Comment: Block scoping advantages: more legible code, avoids hoisting confusion with var. I believe the JavaScript TC39's goal is to eventually phase out `var` in favor of `let` and `const`.

Comment: @ffxsam I'm with @Blindman67. If you're using `let` to avoid hoisting issues or help with legibility, your functions are too large.