# ES6 fat arrow syntax underscore

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any specific difference between using `()` in the fat arrow syntax vs `_`

E.g: Is there a difference between:

`<Button onPress={ () => { Actions.home() } }> Click to login </Button>`

vs

`<Button  onPress={ _=> { Actions.home() } }> Click to login </Button>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427800/empty-parentheses-vs-underscore-for-es6-no-args-arrow-functions looks like no real difference

Comment: _Technically_ no difference - they both don't use anything that's passed in. However, using the `_ => ...` syntax shows that the function takes a parameter but it's ignored, thus being more explicit about the intention.

Comment: Does this code even make sense? onPress={ _=> { Actions.home() } } I didn't meet with anything like this yet, maybe because of it's low quality or my adventure with js is too short? Wouldn't `onPress="Actions.home()"` be enough?

Comment: @K.Daniek `Actions.home` - adding the `()` at the end will execute the function immediately.